# Chrome Extension localization issue when adding it -- says i didnt specify default locale even though i did

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, manifest

**Error Message**:
"Package is invalid. Details: 'Localization used, but default_locale wasn't specified in the manifest.'.

**Problem:**
I have created a custom extension and specified a default locale, but chrome wont allow me to add it to the extension bar and throws the above message. i also have the _locales folder in my directory as necessary. Might it have something to do with that folder or its location?

**Manifest:**

```
{
    "name": "NAMENAMENAMENAME",
    "short_name": "xxx",
    "version": "0.0.3",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "description": "This does something or other.",
        "browser_action": {
            "default_icon": {
            "16": "icons/yokel16.jpg",
            "48": "icons/yokel48.jpg",
            "default_title": "CCJ",
            "default_popup": "popup.html"
            }
        },
   "icons": {
       "16": "icons/yokel16.jpg",
       "19": "icons/yokel19.jpg",
       "48": "icons/yokel48.jpg",
       "128": "icons/yokel128.jpg"
       },
   "default_locale": "en",
       "background": {
           "page": "popup.js",
           "persistent": false
        },
  "permissions": [
     "cookies",
     "history",
     "tabs",
     "{{some URL}}"
     ]
}
```

Comment: Finally, how you solved this?

Answer (score 1):

Your manifest seems to be invalid altogether: `"browser_action"` keys spilled into `"default_icon"`.

That probably throws Chrome off, and it gives a wrong error message (complains about missing `default_locale` before complaining about malformed manifest).

You have:

```
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": {
        "16": "icons/yokel16.jpg",
        "48": "icons/yokel48.jpg",
        "default_title": "CCJ",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
        }
    },
```

Should be (generate appropriate icon sizes, 16 and 48 are not what Chrome expects):

```
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": {
            "19": "icons/yokel48.jpg",
            "38": "icons/yokel48.jpg"
        },
        "default_title": "CCJ",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
```